# send non-delivery notification

Tags: mail.app, mobileme, email, spam

I am fairly sure MobileMe (and possibly Mail.App) had a feature which allowed you to send a non-delivery notification for an email. This is possibly the best way to battle spam, however I can not find this feature anywhere now. Has it been removed or is it hidden somewhere else?

Comment: It was called bounce. They eliminated it in Lion.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mail/4.0/en/9919.html) suggests that the feature exists in Mail under Lion. The feature, however, does not appear to exist, either as a toolbar option, nor as a Message menu command, nor as a context menu command, nor as an item in the Help file for Mail. The aforelinked document says "Lion" in its title, but refers to Mail 4.0; the Mail program under Lion is Mail 5.1.

[image]

This may or may not have anything to do with [Apple's acknowledgement that bounce does not always dissuade spammers](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3498).